# reading not well formed xml in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am receiving a xml from some application. This xml is not well formed.
like

How to read this in spring batch?

Comment: <header>
 <tag1></tag1>
</header
<message>
 <sometag></sometag>
</message>
<trailer>
 <somemoretag></somemoretag>
</trailer>

Answer (score 0):

The `StaxEventItemReader` is really dependent upon the unmarshaller that you provide.  If you can define one that can handle your unvalid markup, that would work.  Otherwise, you'll have to just write your own, custom `ItemReader` implementation.

Comment: Thanks,I think , I will convert xml into well formed xml and use StaxEventItemReader .